# Solve for x and y And z In the following equation :1/(x+z) =3 ,x(y+z) = 32 and x+y+z =12.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for x and y And z In the following equation :1/(x+z) =3 ,x(y+z) = 32 and x+y+z =12.

I tried making x the subject of the formula x=12-y-z
I transformed the first eqn 3x +3z = 1
Then I substituted x = 12-y-z Into 3x +3z =1
This gives y = 35/3 after simplify 
But substituting y into the other eqn gives  0
Am really confused

Answer (score 2):

If 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{x+z}=3 & (1)\\
x(y+z)=32 & (2)\\
x+y+z=12 & (3)\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
then by (1) $x+z=\frac{1}{3}$. Plug it into (3) gives $y+\frac{1}{3}=12$. Hence 
$y=\frac{35}{3}$. We are let with two equations, namely 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{x+z}=3 & (1)\\
x(\frac{35}{3}+z)=32 & (2)\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
By (1), $z=\frac{1}{3}-x$. Plug it into (2) gives 
$$
x(\frac{35}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-x)=32
$$
Hence $x=4$ or $x=8$. Therefore, the final solutions are $(4,\frac{35}{3},-\frac{11}{3})$ or $(8,\frac{35}{3},-\frac{23}{3})$.

Answer (score 0):

$y + z = \frac{32}x$

$x + y + z = 12$

$x + \frac {32}x = 12$

$x^2 -12x + 32 = 0$

Find value of $x$ from above equation.

Then from first equation you can find $z$. And from last equation $y$.

Comment: If still doubt let me know.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x+z}=3 \tag 1$$

$$x(y+z)=32 \tag2$$

$$x+y+z=12 \tag3$$

From $(2)$ put $ y+z=\dfrac{32}{x}$ in $(3)$ (Assuming $y+z \neq0$)

You'll get $$x^2-12x+32=0 \implies x=8,4$$

Now, corresponding to  $x=8$, we get $z=-\dfrac{23}{3}$  and $y=\dfrac{35}{3}$ (Using $(1)$ ,$(2)$ and $(3)$)

And, corresponding to  $x=4$, we get $z=-\dfrac{11}{3}$  and $y=\dfrac{35}{3}$
(Using $(1)$ ,$(2)$ and $(3)$)

So finally, solutions are : $$(x,y,z) = \Big (4,\frac{35}{3},-\frac{11}{3}\Big ) ; \Big (4,\frac{35}{3},-\frac{23}{3}\Big ) $$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{1}{x+z} = 3 \implies 3(x+z) = 1, \quad (1)$$
$$ x(y+z) = 32, \quad (2)$$
$$ x+y+z = 12. \quad (3)$$

$$ \begin{align}
(3)&\implies 3(x+y+z) = 1 + 3y = 36\\
   &\implies y = 35/3\\
(2)&\implies x(3y+3z) = 96 \\
 &\implies x(35 + 1 - 3x) = 96 \\
&\implies x(12-x) = 32\\
&\implies x^2 - 12x + 32 = 0\\
&\implies (x-8)(x-4) = 0 \\
&\implies x = 4, 8.
\end{align}
$$

From $(1)$:
$$x = 4 \implies z = -11/3$$
$$x = 8 \implies z = -23/3$$

Thus, there are 2 sets of solutions:

$$ (x,y,z) \in \{ (4, 35/3, -11/3),\; (8, 35/3, -23/3\}. $$